# Laravel 5.5 - Pass MySQL query to Javascript function/DataTables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to pass a SQL query to a Javascript function, found in my view, which will populate a HTML table using the DataTables API. I'm having trouble converting the object array into plain JSON. How would I go about doing so?

[web.php]

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    $users = DB::connection('mysql')->select('SELECT * FROM users');
    return view('admin', compact('users'));
});
```

[admin.blade.php] (HTML)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Users</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-compact" width="100%" id="userTable" cellspacing="0"></table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[admin.blade.php] (Javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#userTable').DataTable( {
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": '55vh',
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            dom: 'ft',
            "aaData": "{{ $users }}",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sTitle": "Name",   "mData": "name" },
                { "sTitle": "Email",  "mData": "email" },
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

[Example JSON object/array returned from database]

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#195
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "Josh_W"
    +"email": "user@email.com"
    +"group": "Admin"
    +"level": 5
    +"password": "PASSWORD"
    +"remember_token": null
    +"created_at": "2017-10-12 14:42:38"
    +"updated_at": "2017-10-12 14:42:38"
  }
]
```

Comment: A) Why are you bypassing Eloquent? B) What happens if you have more than a trivial number of users? Are you really going to show 10,000 rows?

Comment: Great question @tadman! Looking past the "admin" model shown above, I plan to attach a series of remote databases to the overall project that will only perform select queries (no editing capability). From my understanding, Eloquent requires a class to model each database. I prefer not to make 20 - 30 additional classes if it's not necessary.

Comment: The whole point of Eloquent is to make those classes easy to construct. They're there for a reason: That's where you can put in model-specific functionality in there, like how the models relate to the others. Presumably you have some kind of relationships, it's odd to see a schema with zero in the way of those, so not using Eloquent means you're missing out on the major reason for using it in the first place.

Comment: So in short, while not technically "necessary', it's how things are done in Laravel and doing it properly makes your life significantly easier. Smashing around with raw queries should be a last resort.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate your insight. I'll reconsider my design approach and take another look at Eloquent. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select()` method returns an array. You need to `collect()` the array and then call `toJson()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#userTable').DataTable( {
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": '55vh',
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            dom: 'ft',
            "aaData": {!! collect($users)->toJson() !!},
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sTitle": "Name",   "mData": "name" },
                { "sTitle": "Email",  "mData": "email" },
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

To avoid escaping your JSON use the `{!! !!}` syntax.

See the [Laravel documentation on collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-tojson) and [displaying data on views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I receive the following error: "Exception message: Call to a member function toJson() on array"

Comment: I attempted the change to my existing code and still no luck. Also, my query yields results with the current syntax. I'm able to perform a "{{ dd($users) }}" and see the correct JSON from my database.

Comment: You are right, the `select()` method already runs the query. It also returns an array instead of a collection. I updated my answer, see the `collect()` I added.

Comment: I've added an example output from the database. I tried the collect() method and received the following error: "DataTables warning: table id=userTable - Requested unknown parameter 'name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

Comment: That's a problem with JavaScript. I think it's because of the quotes around the JSON. Remove them and try again. Updating my answer again.

Comment: We're getting really close! I didn't get any errors this time. My table didn't populate but the JSON is visible within the loaded page source code but contains "&quot;name&quot;" thoughout the entire JSON array. Is that normal?

Comment: Almost there! I think you need to use `{!! collect($users)->toJson() !!}` to unscape the JSON. Updating my answer!

Comment: Note: I replaced every instance of "&quot;" with an actual quotation and it populated the table with the hard-coded JSON

Comment: That did the trick! The table is populating correctly with data from the database! Thank you so much for your expertise!

Comment: I sure did and I'm jumping with joy haha Thanks again!

Comment: One additional note. When using `DB::connection()` to run queries, I think it always returns arrays instead of collections.